# Find All Rows By A Certain Date/Any Year

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building an application with Symfony2 and I need to create a custom function for a repository that can select all rows that were made by a certain user and that fall under a certain month/day but for any year.

So I want to pass a certain day and user into the repo and get any entries that were made on that day, from any year.

Is there anyway to do this via the query builder or do I need to pull them all and sort them with PHP in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
public function fetchByDay($day)
{    
    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare('
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        WHERE DAYOFMONTH(date_column) = :day
    ');
    $connection->bindValue('day', (int) $day, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $connection->execute();

    return $connection->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

here is a [documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This will take a few steps:

- Add the [beberlei\Doctrine extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) by adding to composer.json: 
  `"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*"`
- Modify `...app/config/config.yml` to include

> ```
> doctrine:
> ...
>     orm:
> ...
>         dql:
>             datetime_functions: 
>                 Day: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
>                 Month: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
> ```

Then, assuming the rows appear in an entity that has a ManyToOne relationship with User, you can build a query in a repository such as:

```
public function getSomeStuff($user, $day, $month)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                        "SELECT r FROM YourBundle:RowSource r "
                        . "JOIN YourBundle:User u "
                        . "WITH r.user = u "
                        . "WHERE Month(r.rowDate) = $month AND "
                        . "Day(r.rowDate) = $day AND "
                        . "r.user = $user "
            )->getResult();
}
```